# BlockingCollection or Queue<T> for jobs?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, jobs

I am developing a windows forms application ( c# ), and while program is running, it creates objects adds them to a list. I have to process the items in the list , with FIFO ( first in first out ). I want to do this in a backgroundthread and i have to process them in order, number 1 , number 2, number 3 and so on. And as soon as an item gets added to the list i want to process it. So i have to have something to check that list.

What is the best way to achieve this?

I know that blockingcollection does something similar, that it waits for an item to be added before processing it.

I can use a single thread with the Queue and just while(true) and take items if there is any?

What do you think?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sounds like you should go for the [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) if you're planning on using a background thread. You can pretty easily do the same `while(true)` logic that you're looking for.

The `BlockingCollection<T>` gives you two important features

1. It's thread-safe
2. When you call [`Take()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287085.aspx), it will block(i.e. wait until something is in the queue) for you, so you don't have to write any code with [`ManualResetEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) and the like, which is a nice simplification.

Comment: Yes exactly ! I am just asking this to confirm my thought and if someome have a better idea :)

Comment: @Jonathan Beerhalter: Or, instead of calling `Take`, he could just have his background thread do a `foreach` on [`GetConsumingEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx), which will yield the items as they are placed in the `BlockingCollection<T>`.

Comment: @syncis: `GetConsumingEnumerable` will block until an item is added to the `BlockingCollection<T>` just like `Take` will; the thing is, what else is your background thread doing other than processing these items?  If you are trying to save threads; don't, you are basically re-writing the thread pool and that's not generally a good idea.  Note, more items can come in for `Take` or yielded through `GetConsumingEnumerable` while you are processing your items one by one (or you can send those items off to be processed in other threads, depending on your needs).

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to block if the queue is empty then use `BlockingCollection` - it is ideal...
IF you want it more Queue-like (decide yourself how to deal with an empty) then `ConcurrentQueue`.

Both are thread-safe, in `ConcurrentQueue` most operations are implemented lock-free so really fast... either way use it directly or as the base type for your `BlockingCollection` for example `BlockingCollection<string> = new BlockingCollection<string> (new ConcurrentQueue<string>)`  - you can even put a maximum capactiy on that (optional second param of constructor).