# Threads monitoring a Queue<Actions>

Tags: c#, multithreading, snmp

I doing a small project to map a network (routers only) using SNMP. In order to speed things up, I´m trying to have a *pool* of threads responsible for doing the jobs I need, apart from the first job which is done by the main thread.

At this time I have two jobs, one takes a parameter the other doesn´t:

- `UpdateDeviceInfo(NetworkDevice nd)`
- `UpdateLinks()` *not defined yet

What I´m trying to achieve is to have those working threads waiting for a job to
appear on a `Queue<Action>` and wait while it is empty. The main thread will add the first job and then wait for all workers, which might add more jobs, to finish before starting adding the second job and wake up the sleeping threads.

My problem/questions are:

- How to define the `Queue<Actions>` so that I can insert the methods and the parameters if any. If not possible I could make all functions accept the same parameter.
- How to launch the *working* threads indefinitely. I not sure where should I create the `for(;;)`.

This is my code so far:

```
public enum DatabaseState
{
    Empty = 0,
    Learning = 1,
    Updating = 2,
    Stable = 3,
    Exiting = 4
};

public class NetworkDB
{
    public Dictionary<string, NetworkDevice> database;
    private Queue<Action<NetworkDevice>> jobs;
    private string _community;
    private string _ipaddress;

    private Object _statelock = new Object();
    private DatabaseState _state = DatabaseState.Empty;

    private readonly int workers = 4;
    private Object _threadswaitinglock = new Object();
    private int _threadswaiting = 0;

    public Dictionary<string, NetworkDevice> Database { get => database; set => database = value; }

    public NetworkDB(string community, string ipaddress)
    {
        _community = community;
        _ipaddress = ipaddress;
        database = new Dictionary<string, NetworkDevice>();
        jobs = new Queue<Action<NetworkDevice>>();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        NetworkDevice nd = SNMP.GetDeviceInfo(new IpAddress(_ipaddress), _community);
        if (nd.Status > NetworkDeviceStatus.Unknown)
        {
            database.Add(nd.Id, nd);
            _state = DatabaseState.Learning;
            nd.Update(this); // The first job is done by the main thread 

            for (int i = 0; i < workers; i++)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(JobRemove);
                t.Start();
            }

            lock (_statelock)
            {
                if (_state == DatabaseState.Learning)
                {
                    Monitor.Wait(_statelock);
                }
            }

            lock (_statelock)
            {
                if (_state == DatabaseState.Updating)
                {
                    Monitor.Wait(_statelock);
                }
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, NetworkDevice> n in database)
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(n.Value.Name + ".txt")
                {
                    file.WriteLine(n);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void JobInsert(Action<NetworkDevice> func, NetworkDevice nd)
    {
        lock (jobs)
        {
            jobs.Enqueue(item);
            if (jobs.Count == 1)
            {
                // wake up any blocked dequeue
                Monitor.Pulse(jobs);
            }
        }
    }

    public void JobRemove()
    {
        Action<NetworkDevice> item;
        lock (jobs)
        {
            while (jobs.Count == 0)
            {
                lock (_threadswaitinglock)
                {
                    _threadswaiting += 1;
                    if (_threadswaiting == workers)
                        Monitor.Pulse(_statelock);
                }
                Monitor.Wait(jobs);
            }

            lock (_threadswaitinglock)
            {
                _threadswaiting -= 1;
            }

            item = jobs.Dequeue();
            item.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public bool NetworkDeviceExists(NetworkDevice nd)
    {
        try
        {
            Monitor.Enter(database);
            if (database.ContainsKey(nd.Id))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                database.Add(nd.Id, nd);
                Action<NetworkDevice> action = new Action<NetworkDevice>(UpdateDeviceInfo);
                jobs.Enqueue(action);
                return false;
            }
        }
        finally
        {

            Monitor.Exit(database);
        }
    }

    //Job1 - Learning -> Update device info
    public void UpdateDeviceInfo(NetworkDevice nd)
    {
        nd.Update(this);
        try
        {
            Monitor.Enter(database);
            nd.Status = NetworkDeviceStatus.Self;
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(database);
        }
    }

    //Job2 - Updating -> After Learning, create links between neighbours
    private void UpdateLinks()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Would a `BlockingCollection` fit your needs?

Comment: What do the different `DatabaseState`s mean exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BlockingCollection or Queue<T> for jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161104/blockingcollection-or-queuet-for-jobs)

Comment: DatabaseState is the the current state. Empty if i cannot access the first device. Learning while is looking up at each device routing table and jumping for each neighbour. Updating, after for creating the links between devices. I choose to create a state for this because I only know which neigbhour inteface is used for link with the current one, only after learning all about the neighbour. Exititng, would be the where I would signal every thread to stop. I will use this on a windows service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet seems like using a BlockingCollection instead of the Queue class. They behave effectively the same in terms of FIFO, but a BlockingCollection will let each of your threads block until an item can be taken by calling GetConsumingEnumerable or Take. Here is a complete example.

http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2012/11/using-blockingcollection-to-communicate.html?m=1

As for including the parameters, it seems like you could use closure to enclose the NetworkDevice itself and then just enqueue Action instead of Action<>

Comment: BlockingCollection seems a good replacement for the Queue class. Thx.

Comment: Regarding the Action, I need to reference which NetworkDevice will do each method, because not all NetworkDevice  can do all methods. For example if my SNMP credentials don´t work for a particular device, I won´t queue that NetworkDevice for an Update.

Comment: In that case using closure definitely sounds like a good choice